# windows phone, change hour phone httpclient web api 404 error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, http-status-code-404, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I have a windows phone app, that tries a log in to a web api with a HttpClient call.

If the hour of the phone is correct:

```
DateTime.Now == "19/02/2015";
```

then the HttpClient returns a OK status code.

But if the hour of the phone is incorrect (past)

```
DateTime.Now == "19/02/2010";
```

then the HttpClient returns a 404 error, why is this, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Does this happen with any URI?

Comment: With any url of the web api, but I have found what it was, I was using https, if i use http it works, but I don't know why